The support of the functions in the closed span of the Rademacher functions in $L_1(0,1)$
Given a measurable function $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$, we denote by $M(f)$ the measure of the set $\{t\in (0,1) : f(t)\neq 0\}$.
It is not difficult to prove that if $(f_n)$ is a normalized sequence in $L_1(0,1)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}M(f_n)=0$ then $(f_n)$ has a subsequence equivalent to the unit vector basis of $\ell_1$.
Therefore, if $Y$ is a reflexive subspace of $L_1(0,1)$ then $\inf_{f\in Y,\, \|f\|_1=1} M(f)>0$.
QUESTION: Let $[r_n]_{n=0}^\infty$ be the closed subspace of $L_1(0,1)$ generated by the Rademacher functions, with $r_0= \chi_{(0,1)}$, $r_1= \chi_{(0,1/2)}- \chi_{(1/2,1)}, r_2=\chi_{(0,1/4)}- \chi_{(1/4,1/2)}+ \chi_{(1/2,3/4)}- \chi_{(3/4,1)},\ldots$,  which is isomorphic to $\ell_2$.
Note that $r_0+r_1= 2\chi_{(0,1/2)}$.
Is $\inf_{f\in [r_n]_{n=0}^\infty, \|f\|_1=1}M(f_n)= 1/2$?

I think this is clear essentially because if $f=c_0r_0+c_1r_1+\ldots$, then $f(x+1/2)=f(x)-2c_1$, so $f$ can vanish at at most one of $x, x+1/2$ if $c_1\not= 0$. If $c_1=0$, then an analogous argument works for a higher coefficient.

@ChristianRemling: Since the Rademachers are IID, WLOG $c_1 \not= 0$.

@ChristianRemling: Thank you for your answer.
